# How to output to both log file and STDOUT in new Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a new environment file in my Rails 4 app (`config/environments/staging.rb`).  The settings in this file are exactly those found in the default `development.rb` file created when the app was generated.

When firing up WEBrick in the console using this environment (`rails s -e staging` or `RAILS_ENV=staging rails s`), I don't see anything written to STDOUT.  I can see the log file for the staging environment being written to, but nothing in STDOUT.  I understand I can tail the file, but I was wondering if there was a config setting to handle this.  I can also redirect the Rails logger to output everything to STDOUT, but how can I get my custom environment to write to both STDOUT and the log file?

I can replicate this on both OSX and Windows with a new Rails 4 app, and the default environments work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Modify your environment config file to use the `Rails::Rack::LogTailer` middleware:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, Rails::Rack::LogTailer)
end
```